# Multicast в локальной сети

Tags: vlc

Отправляю Udp пакеты в локальной сети. Сеть 192.168.0.0 Маска 255.255.255.0 Сейчас я отправляю с адреса скажем 192.168.0.58 на конкретный на адрес 192.168.0.38 и получаю их на этом адресе. Как отправить пакеты что бы можно было получить их на любом адресе указанной локальной сети?

vlc.exe dshow://  :dshow-vdev="none" :dshow-adev="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"  --sout=#transcode{acodec="u8  ",channels=1,samplerate=8000,ab=128}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=raw,dst=192.168.0.38:4210}}

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам себе как , собственно, и планировал эту акцию. Попытатся собрать мысли в кучку ,изложить их эпистолярно, что вследствии должно было привести к правильному решению.

Все достаочно просто:
вещаю на какой то типа мультикаст адрес скажем 224.255.1.1
vlc.exe dshow://  :dshow-vdev="none" :dshow-adev="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"  --sout=#transcode{acodec="u8  ",channels=1,samplerate=8000,ab=128}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=raw,dst=224.255.1.1:4210}}
а потом на этом адресе уже принимаю на любом компе в сети
vlc --demux=rawaud --rawaud-channels=1 --rawaud-samplerate=8000 --rawaud-fourcc "u8  " udp://@224.255.1.1:4210
вот и весь мультикаст